# How to pass data between two pages in Windows Phone 8.1 application ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have a Windows phone 8.1 application where I have two pages displaying data. The first page has a listview displaying all of the data from an sqlite database, and when the user taps on one item in the listview, the second page opens with a listview that contains more details about that specific record from the database. My question is how to achieve this in Windows Phone 8.1 using c# ?

Answer (score 1):

in windows phone 8.1 there are two ways to do it:

```
     void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs    e)
    {
      var list= sender as Listview;
      var taped=list.SelectedItem as Model;
      //here you send your parameter to the second page
      Frame.Navigate(Typeof(SecondPage),taped);
    }
```

or

```
    public static Model taped;
     void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs    e)
    {
      var list= sender as Listview;
      taped=list.SelectedItem as Model;


    }
```

and in the SecondPage you can acces to it via FirstPage.taped;

Answer (score 1):

On first page you should write something like this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), someData);
```

For second page you should override OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e ).
For example:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
{
    MyData data = e.Parameter as MyData.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

- To directly pass data, you can put it in the URI as a querystring parameter (like a web page URL). So, for example, instead of navigating to `secondpage.xaml`, you could navigate to `secondpage.xaml?param1=abc123&param2=<base64 data>`. You pick up the navigation parameter by overriding the `onNavigatedTo` function, same as you would do for checking the parameters that an app was launched with (but not, presumably, on the start page). Note that this may be Silverlight-specific; I haven't tried it with non-Silverlight apps.
- To just pass data around the app in general, you can use any number of global objects. You can add a public field to the `App` class (as defined in `App.xaml.cs`) that you read and write from other classes. You can add a *static* public field in any class, and read and write from it. Globals are considered a bad design, but sticking them on the specific classes that are supposed to access them is reasonable. Note that different pages might sometimes be processed on different threads.
- Use persistent storage. You can write to the isolated storage settings dictionary, or just write out a file and have the other page look for it. That's probably overkill for what you're trying to achieve, but it would be a viable solution if, for example, you wanted to have one part of the app record a lot of video from the camera, and another part process it.