# Windows Phone Development: How to pass tapped SQLite item from one page to another?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

Hi this question is exactly the same as this question posted on stackoverflow earlier: [How to pass data between two pages in Windows Phone 8.1 application ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950020/how-to-pass-data-between-two-pages-in-windows-phone-8-1-application)

I have two pages on my Windows Phone 8.1 app. The first page contains a listview that displays the data from a sqlite database. When a user tapped on an item displayed, it should bring them to the second page where there is more details of the selected item, queried from the sqlite database. How do I do this?

And the first answer by Riadh Ben Hassine seems like a good solution. However, as my reputation is not high enough, I cannot comment to ask him more on the solution. I do not understand his approach (line by line analysis would be appreciated). When I use his suggestion, "Model" has a red squiggly line under it, saying the type Model could not be found. What assembly reference do I need to use?

Thank you.

Code in Page 1:

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = sender as ListView;
        var tapped = list.SelectedItem as Model;
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), tapped);
    }
```

Code in Page 2 under NavigatedTo:

```
Model tapped = e.Parameter as Model;
        if (e.Parameter != null)
        {
            //Something
        }
```

I have tried putting "Model tapped = e.Parameter as Model" inside the if loop too. But it didn't work.

Comment: if you use just the code that i have posted it should works fine, maybe you have some kind of if statement that blocks the navigation

Answer (score 0):

The `Model` should be the class that you pass to the `ListView`, for example if the source of your `ListView` is a `List<Model>` you cast the selected item to `Model`, if the source is a `List<SQLiteItem>` you have to cast it to `SQLiteItem`.

```
    void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs    e)
    {
      var list = sender as Listview;

      var tapped = list.SelectedItem as Model; // Model is your datamodel

      //here you send your parameter to the second page
      Frame.Navigate(Typeof(SecondPage),tapped);
    }
```

In the second page you retrieve it in this way:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
{
    Model tapped = e.Parameter as Model.
}
```

xaml

```
<ListView SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged" />
```

Comment: OOH!! Thank you so much. However, how do I accessed "taped"?? I can't accessed it with "FirstPage.taped", there is no taped under FirstPage.

Comment: i have edited the response to show you how to get the parameter in the second page

Comment: What do I put under ItemClick event? If I put the code under SelectionChanged event, tapping on the item would not navigate to secondpage. And if I put those code under ItemClick event, it will navigate but it does not give me the information of the tapped item.

Comment: you need to change the event in your xaml from itemclick to  "SelectionChanged" in your xaml. I have added a xaml example

Comment: I have done that, it would not navigate to second page. Tapping on the item does nothing.

Comment: can you post some of your code? Any exception is raised?

Comment: I have edited my question with my code. Really thankful for your help.